# Delay in pop download of mails using fetchmail

Tags: rt, fetchmail

We are using fetchmail to retrieve mails from different mailboxes and create tickets in queues configured in the request tracker. Fetching mail from one of the mail-ids is taking long. Anybody had similar experience? What can be the possible reasons for delay or any means to debug it?

One approach I tried was to spawn another fetchmail process for the mail causing delay, but request tracker mandates being run by root user and a single user cannot run multiple fetchmail process at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of digging into apache logs, I was able to figure it out that the size of the mails being downloaded from the one particular mailbox was quite large, which in turn cause the timeout.

Changing the FcgidIOTimeout configuration from 90 to 180 in the following configuration file helped.
*/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf.*